# How to use the "randint" output in an if statement?

Tags: python, random, import

this is my first question on stack overflow.
I'm still learning python so I wanted to make something fun, but not very advanced. I want to know how to make a random number into an if statement. Here is my code:

```
import random
print("Congratulations! You are our ")
print(random.randint(0, 200))
print(" Caller!")
if (randint >= 200);{
print("Oops, you lost!")
}
```

I tried but it kept showing errors.

Comment: Check docs for if statement: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the same number again, you must assign it to a variable first. Something like:

```
import random   
randnum = random.randint(0, 200)
print("Congratulations! You are our ")
print(randnum)
print(" Caller!")
if (randnum >= 200):
    print("Oops, you lost!")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read some basic info about conditions in python, e.g. here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp

as for your code, this will work:

```
print("Congratulations! You are our ")
randint = random.randint(0, 200)
print(randint)
print(" Caller!")
if randint >= 100:
  print("Oops, you lost!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the random number you created.

```
import random

random_number = random.randint(0, 200)
print(f"Congratulations! You are our {random_number} Caller!")
if random_number >= 200:
    print("Oops, you lost!")
```

With the current values you won't see the output in the `if` block often, because the maximum of the number is 200.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code'd look like when it is fixed:

```py
import random

print("Congratulations! You are our ")
print(random.randint(0, 200))
print(" Caller!")
if random.randint(0, 200) >= 200:
    print("Oops, you lost!")
```

So first of all you don't use `;` and `{}` to denote an if block in python, rather you use `:` and indentation like in the above example.

Also you tried to refer to a variable called `randint` which was not defined yet, or maybe you wanted to call the same `random.randint` function like you did above.
Either way make sure to define variables and assign value to them in order to compare them in an if condition or properly call functions.